# how to randomly generate a number based on particular probability in R?

Tags: python, r

I have a dataset as follow, all activity group is belong to leisure activity.

```
activity_group    probability
    a           0.4
    b           0.2
    c           0.33
    d           0.07
```

There are 10 person, the time this 10 people spend in leisure activity will follow normal distribution(μ,σ).I need a function to stochastically make time for this people spend on different  activity group. For example, depending on this normal distribution, person A will spend n hours in leisure activity, after function, it will give a how many hour in each activity group.

for example, the average time this 10 people spend in leisure activity, which includes a,b,c,d this four types, is 2 hours per day. So depending on this probability, is there any function allow me to get how this person assign this 2 hours for this four activity.

I got hind from Ben_aaron, another user in Stack Overflow. I may try

```
 #mynumbers = rnorm(size,mean,sigma) 
 mynumbers = rnorm(10,2,0.4) 
 myprob = c(.4, .3, .33, .07) #your probabilities
 d = sample(mynumbers,
       size = 10, 
       replace = T,
       prob = myprob)
```

But it is not working, shows error information:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

Comment: (1) A normal distribution will theoretically lead to some negative values. Are you willing to assume that mu/sigma is large enough that we can ignore that possibility? (2) Am I right that after picking the total amount of time spent in leisure activity, you want to subdivide the total into components spent in a, b, c, d, with the correct average means of the proportions in each group? (Are all of the values allowed to be continuous?)  (I would suggest choosing randomly from a *Dirichlet distribution* for this - if you clarify your question I can post an example.)

Comment: thanks for the reminder! I didn't realize there will be negative if using normal distribution. Sorry for any unclearly description.  So my question, for example, the average time this 10 people spend in leisure activity, which includes a,b,c,d this four types, is 2 hours per day. So depending on this probability, is there any function allow me to get how this person assign this 2 hours for this four activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
with(
  df,
  table(replicate(10, sample(activity_group, 1, prob = probability)))
)
```

the output looks like

```
a b c d
4 1 4 1
```